# How do I count multiple levels of referrals (A referred B, B referred C, D & E, E referred F, G, H, I, etc)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup, countif

I have a referral system where you get credit for referring other customers.  If those customers refer other customers they get some level of credit for those as well.  We need to count not only how many times a person has referred someone, but how many people that person referred (and how many that person referred, and so on).  Up to seven levels of contact.

Here is some sample data:

[image]

So cathy.irwin@fakemale.com referred derickmcewen@Bmail.net & canuccio@faakemail.com, so gets credit for 2 referrals.

But derickmcewen@Bmail.net referred forza65@phailmail.net, so derick gets credit for one direct referral and cathy gets credit for two direct and one 2nd level referral.

forza65@phailmail.net referred AKOVALY@fakemail2.COM, cars@pretend.com, georgew@fake.com & jenn@volzfake.com, so forza gets credit for 4 1st level referrals, derick gets credit for 4 2nd level referrals and cathy gets credit for one 2nd level & four 3rd level, etc.

The direct/1st level referrals I can do with a simple COUNTIF formula, but I'm not sure how to count the number of referrals for each other level. I need a formula that can work for each person.  Here is how I have my report set up:

[image]

So I need formulas that can calculate the other levels for each person.  I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it, any ideas?

Comment: this is really a job for a proper relational database, if it is at all possible. Note that the whole scheme dies a fiery death if someone changes their email address, as there are no enforced, unique customer IDs. I think this is basically a simple "linked list"

Comment: I think the terminology for this table structure is "self-referencing". If your excel version is newer, you might be able to nest  a `=xlookup()` in a `count()`.

Comment: Yea, I know a database would handle this much easier, but is there a way to do it in Excel?  I guess I'm not worried about e-mail addresses changing, the idea is to create a formula structure that data pulled from their system can just be dropped in.

Comment: And thanks for the terms, I wasn't really sure how to even describe this in a way that I could search for guides.  I'll look up info on self-referencing & linked lists.

Comment: Ok, I've got some progress with a nested XLOOKUP.  

This gives me the third level:
=XLOOKUP(XLOOKUP(D11,H:H,C:C),H:H,C:C)

But it only shows me the first person on that level.  So if the first person refers 3 people, it looks up the first person and returns the first person that person referred.  When I put it into a COUNT it just produces 1.

Comment: The FILTER function will return all the people referred for the first level.  If I can nest this it'll work... I'm having trouble with that though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works based on a brief scan....

**Cell D2 Formula**:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,$B:$C,2,FALSE)
```

Drag this across to column I, and down.

**Cell J2 formula**:

```
=COUNTIF(C:C,$B2)
```

Drag this across and down.

Output...

[image]

Comment: Not as compact as I was hoping for, but it totally works.  Thank you!  I hope you don't mind, but I'll hold off on accepting this answer for now to see if anyone has a solution that works without all the extra columns.  And yea, this problem makes my head hurt too, haha.

Comment: Sounds good, good luck.

Comment: It works, but unfortunately all the VLOOKUPs this requires (especially since the sheet has 7,000+ rows) slows things down immensely.  I tried doing a double vlookup but it isn't working for some reason.